# Find range of cells containing specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in Excel and I have a task to find range of cells, containing specific text.
My file looks like this:

```
  A   B
1 m1a 5
2 m1b 7
3 m2c 6
4 m2d 8
5 m2e 4
```

I want to get range of cells, containing `m1*` and `m2*`, using VBA. For example, for `m1` answer would be `A1:A2`, for `m2` - `A3:A5`.
Honestly, I want to find only row range, so the better answer would be number of the first row, containing my string, and the last: `1:2` and `3:5`.
How could I find start and end row numbers for my string value using VBA functions?

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far and explain where you ran into trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the search string in cell `C1`

It sounds like the assumption that the data is sorted is valid. If so you can obtain the first row with

```
=MATCH("*"&C1&"*", A1:A5, 0)
```

and the number of rows with

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5, "*"&C1&"*")
```

I havent done any more than that as it sounds like you want to process the info further, but these are the building blocks that unblock you

Putting the asterisks either side of the search string make it a sliding wildcard search

**IN VBA**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function locate_match(ByVal search As String, ByVal As Range) As String
  Dim start As Long
  Dim length As Long

  search = "*" & search & "*"

  start = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(search, r, 0)
  length = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, search)

  locate_match = start & ":" & (start + length - 1)

End Function
```

Comment: I need to do it using VBA

Comment: Then just use these functions in a VBA macro using `Application.worksheetfunction.match(...` and `Application.worksheetfunction.COUNTIF(...` - you know how to do that or you want I update the answer?

Comment: Thank you, didn't occur to me

Comment: see above - just arbitrarily returned a string per your "spec"

Comment: Hi @Angelika - does this answer? Could you upvote/accept/feedback? thanks